# Making a Discord.py bot have 2 prefixes

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I've been trying to make my Discord.py bot have 2 prefixes. For example the first one would be "a!" and the second one would be pinging it, but I can't just figure out how to do it.
Here is my code :

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('$'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a list of prefixes to `command_prefix`, if you want it to include mentions you can also do it like this:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or(["!a", "$"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["hi ","Hi "])
```

Answer (score -1):

use the `or` operator.
Not sure what you're trying to do, and I don't have much experience with discord.py over discord.js, but I'll grab a snippet from the [Discord.py Quickstart page:](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if not message.startswith('a!') or not message.startswith(<bot mention>):
        return
    ...
```

Comment: Using the `on_message` event is terrible practice for any bot with more than 2 commands, please do not recommend using it, you are better off using the `commands` extension.

Comment: Like I said, I don't have experience with discord.py, only discord.js. Not to mention I explained that I pulled the example off of the quickstart guide for discord.py.